# Can I find datatypes of fields returned in a query in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Is there anyway I can get the datatypes of fields returned in a query in mysql. Say I have a query:

```
SELECT a.*,b.* FROM tbl_name a LEFT JOIN other_tbl b ON a.id=b.first_id
```

Is there a command I can use in mysql that will return the names of the fields that this query will return and their datatypes. I know I can potentially create a view using this query and then DESCRIBE that view, but is there any other way I can do it on the fly?

I'm using SQLAlchemy to perform this raw query and my tables are dynamically generated. Is there a SQLAlchemy way if not a MySQL way.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the datatypes from a table with this in MySQL

```
SELECT COLUMN_TYPE
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'a'
```

Comment: Right. But if my query is a join from multiple tables I'd have to parse out the query to see which fields were being returned from which tables and then go find each one of those. Plus if any field is being aggregated or calculated in the query those won't be in this info.